# in python how to find sending email failed ( deliver status )

Tags: python

I want to print sending fail when mail unable to deliver 
condition: when Email format is correct but invalid email

```
@api.multi
    def confirm_submit(self):
        print 'method calling done'
        import smtplib
        from random import randint

        abcd=(randint(2000, 9000))
        print abcd
        otp=str(abcd)
        self.otpp = otp

        receivers =  self.reg_email
        sender = 'asif@gmail.com'
       # receivers = 'asif@gmail.com'

        message = """Welcome to IB =
               """ 

        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.login(user="asif@gmail.com", password="password")


        print "Successfully sent email"
```

Comment: why don't `try:  exception ` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your code doesn't actually send any mail at any point. The immediate delivery could fail, but you get a bounce message after a while (some minutes, hours, or even days). Do you understand the relayed nature of SMTP and how that could affect whether your message was eventually delivered to its final destination, and whether you can know if this happened or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
try:
   smtpObj.starttls()
   smtpObj.login(login, password)
   smtpObj.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients_emails, msg.as_string())
   print("success")
except Exception as e:
   print("failed", e)
```

Comment: with my code i am able to send mail to valid email , but in case of wrong email i am not getting any responce from server